# OAS 3: How I can autopopulate the endpoint name into my responses?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Using swagger made the following api:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
servers: []
info:
  description: This is a simple API
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Simple API

paths:
  /inventory:
    get:
      summary: searches inventory
      description: |
        By passing in the appropriate options, you can search for
        available inventory in the system
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: searchString
          description: pass an optional search string for looking up inventory
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: search results matching criteria
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
                  description: "Item names"
        '400':
          description: bad input parameter
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  '/inventory': 
                    type: boolean
                  message:
                    type: string
  /baka:
    get:
      responses:
        400:
          description: "ERROR"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  '/baka': 
                    type: boolean
                  message:
                    type: string
```

As you can see I use the following pattern for my error responses:

```
endpoint_name: boolean
message: string
```

So how I can create a common response object that swagger will auto-populate with endpoint name?

Comment: May I ask why you include endpoint paths in responses in the first place? This seems redundant. Consumers already know which endpoints they called.

Comment: Well I document an already implemented API that works this way....
That's why!